# Java: Why is my array of objects overwriting all the previous data inside a loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, overwrite

I try to make an array of nodes with a node on a specific place in the array.

For example:
I add a node in the array and set its number to 1.
I add another node in the array on the next position and set its number to 2.
Both nodes got the number 2 now.

Sample of the code:

```
public static String run(InputStream in) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);

    //indicating values
    sc.nextInt(); /* int vertices = */
    int edge = sc.nextInt();
    int start = sc.nextInt();
    int end = sc.nextInt();

    if (start == end) {
        sc.close();
        Path = "yes";
    } else {
        nodes = new Node[edge + 1];
        for (int i = 1; i < edge; i++) {

            //Node values
            int number = sc.nextInt();
            int next = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextInt(); /* int distance = */

            Node node = new Node(number, next);

            if (nodes[number] == null) {
                nodes[number] = (node);
            } else {
                nodes[number].addChild(next);
            }
        }
        hasPath(nodes[start], end);

    }
    sc.close();

    return Path;
}
```

Sample of the Node code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node {

private ArrayList<Integer> childs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private static int number;

public Node(int n, int next){
    number = n;
    childs.add(next);
}

public int getNumber(){
    return number;
}

public void addChild(int child){
    childs.add(child);
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with declaring the `number` member **`static`**. This means there's only one such member for the `Node` **class**, instead of each **instance** having its own member. Just define it as an instance variable, and you should be fine:

```
public class Node {
    private ArrayList<Integer> childs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private int number; // Note the static was removed
    // rest of the class
```

Comment: That did the job, thnx!

Comment: @EmielRietdijk: If this solved your problem you should mark it as "Accepted"!